# Viewport meta tag to fit a 460px page across all device widths?

Tags: html, css, mobile, width, viewport

I ran into an issue this morning with mobile viewports. I have a webpage developed at 480px and centered on the desktop screen. I want this webpage to scale across the different mobile devices and COVER the WHOLE screen (without cutting anything off). Any ideas on how to this?

I used this meta tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=480, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0 maximum-scale=1.0">
```

Although it does seem to zoom in, it cuts off the right side of the screen. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: try this <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=480">
```

Comment: I tried this as well, this meta tag loads the content at 480px and then zooms back in and cuts of the page at the last minute.

Comment: I apologize that was a silly mistake on my part, it worked perfectly except a small issue. Now, I am seeing a small white space on the left and right side of the content.

Comment: try to set body margin to 0:

  body {
    margin: 0;
  }